# How do you initilize a variable inside a loop

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, println

My code is supposed to keep looping until a valid input is given, ie: if a letter is given it will loop, but if a valid number is given, the code should store it into cSec. Is there anyway to do this?

```
    byte cSec;
    boolean contCSec = true;
    while(contCSec == true) {
        System.out.println("Enter course section: ");
            cSec = sc.nextByte();
        if(cSec>0)
            contCCode = false;
    }
```

cSec can't be used outside the loop.

Comment: Declare AND initialize it within the loop and you should be fine :)

Comment: you cant use it bc there is a trace in which it ends up not initialized. give it a default starting value and handle the case in which it was never changed. then u can use it.

Comment: Unrelated, but `while (contCSec) {...}` is sufficient. What specific issue are you actually having?

Comment: you should add the full error message to your question to make it clear.

Comment: The code is ... odd.  ```contCSec``` is never modified so the loop never ends; ```contCCode``` is used but not defined.  I suppose these are supposed to be the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

A rather less verbose form of what you wrote might be:

```
byte cSec; 
do {
   System.out.println("Enter course section: ");
   cSec = sc.nextByte();
 } while (cSec <= 0);
```

where 'cSec <= 0' denotes an invalid value, per your original, though I imagine there's more to validation than that.

This does not match your title (initialize within loop) since to me that's exactly what you don't want to do.

I think this is clearer than your original since it involved no flag values, and the do...while loop shows up the 'ask then decide to loop' nature a little better.

Adding more validation:

```
byte cSec; 
do {
   System.out.println("Enter course section: ");
   try {
       cSec = sc.nextByte();
   }
   catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
       System.out.println("A number is required");
       cSec = -1;
   }
 } while (cSec <= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to another-dave's wonderful answer, you can suppress the compiler warning by initializing `cSec` outside of the loop.

```
byte cSec = 0;
boolean contCSec = true;
while(contCSec == true) {
    System.out.println("Enter course section: ");
        cSec = sc.nextByte();
    if(cSec>0)
        contCSec = false;
}
```

The reason that you get the warning without the first declaration is because, as strange as it sounds, the compiler does not analyze the contents of your boolean in `while(contCSec == true)`.  It sees that there is a `while` loop, and it sees that there will be a boolean resulting from `(contCSec == true)`, but as far as the compiler is concerned, any boolean going into your while condition could be true, or could be false.  This means that you could enter the while loop, or you could... not.

As far as the compiler is concerned, anything inside the while loop could happen, or could not happen, and there is no way to know without actually running the code.  (If you want to know why this is actually a strict limitation for computers, check out the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).)  That means that the compiler has no idea whether `cSec = sc.nextByte();` will ever happen or not.  Hence, the warning.